# Why isn't my printLevel function working?

Tags: c++, stl, tree, queue

I have written this code to do level order traversal of Binary Search tree. Error is only in printLevel function because all other functions are working fine.

```
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
struct node{
int data;
struct node* left;
struct node* right;
};

struct node* newNode(int data){
struct node* node = new (struct node);
node->data=data;
node->left=NULL;
node->right=NULL;
return (node);
};
struct node* insert (struct node* node, int data){
if (node==NULL){
    return (newNode(data));
}
else {
    if (data<=node->data) node-> left=insert(node->left,data);
    else node->right=insert(node->right,data);
    return (node);
}

}

void printLevel(struct node* node){
    queue<struct node*> q;
    while(node!=NULL){
        cout << node->data << " ";
        q.push(node->left);
        q.push(node->right);
        node=q.front();
    }
}
int main(){
    int n;
    cin >>n;
    int m;
    cin >>m;
    struct node* root=newNode(m);
    for (int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        cin>>m;
        insert(root,m);
    }
    printLevel(root);
//  printPostOrder(root);
//  cout <<maxDepth(root);
//  debug(maxDepth(root),   minValue(root), printTree(root));
    //struct node* root=build123();
}
```

Here is the algorithm: (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/)

printLevelorder(tree)

1) Create an empty queue q

2) temp_node = root /*start from root*/

3) Loop while temp_node is not NULL

```
a) print temp_node->data.

b) Enqueue temp_node’s children (first left then right children) to q

c) Dequeue a node from q and assign it’s value to temp_node
```

I am taking input 3,1,4,2,7,6,5 for 7 nodes. It gets stuck in infinite loop. I have also implemented following two functions based on another method and it is working fine:

```
   void levelOrder(struct node* node, int level ){
    if (node==NULL){
        return;
    }
    if (level==1){
        cout << node->data;
    }
    else if (level>1){
        levelOrder(node->left,level-1);
        levelOrder(node->right,level-1);

    }
}
void printLevelOrder(struct node* root){
    for (int i=1;i<=maxDepth(root);i++){
        levelOrder(root,i);
    }
}
```

It is O(n^2) but above one is O(n). What's wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to step through the code in a debugger, line by line. Including the creation and insertion of nodes into the tree.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your loop termination is wrong.

Instead of `node != NULL`, you should check to see if `!q.empty()`.

Also, the call `q.front` does not remove the element from the queue; to do that, you need `pop` (after calling `front`).

This code works for me:

```
void printLevel(struct node* node){
    std::queue<struct node*> q;
    q.push(node);
    while(!q.empty()) {
        node=q.front();
        q.pop();
        if ( node != NULL ) {
            std::cout << node->data << " ";
            q.push(node->left);
            q.push(node->right);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 your suspicions are well-founded. The actual algorithm is to push the first node on entry, then loop by popping a node from the queue, printing it, pushing its children, the repeat until the queue is empty.